# Need help with a sql query that has an inner and outer join

Tags: sql, syntax, inner-join, outer-join

I really need help getting this query right. I can't share actual table and column names, but will try my best to layout the problem simply.

Assume the following tables. The tables and keys CANNOT be changed. Period. I don't care if you think it's a bad design, this question isn't a design question, it's on SQL syntax.

- Table A - Primary key named id1
- Table B - Contains two foreign keys, TableA.id1 and Foo.id2(ignore Foo, it doesn't matter for this)
- Table C - Contains two foreign keys, TableA.id1 and Foo.id2, additional interesting
  columns.

Constraints:

1. The SQL gets a set of id1s passed in as an argument.
2. It must return a list of Table C rows.
3. It must only return Table C rows where a Table B row exists with a matching TableA.id1 and Foo.id2 - There ARE rows in Table C that don't match Table B
4. A row MUST be returned for every id1 passed in, even if no Table C row exists.

At first I tried a Left Outer Join from Table A to Table B then an Inner Join to Table C. That violates the 4th rule above, as the Inner Join drops out those rows.

Next I tried two Left Outer joins. This is closer, but has the side effect of including rows that match the Table A join to Table B, but don't have a corresponding Table C entry, which isn't what I want.

So, here's what I came up with.

```
SELECT
  a.id1,
  c.*
FROM
  TableB b
INNER JOIN 
  TableC c USING (id1,id2)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
  TableA a USING (id1)
WHERE
  a.id1 in (x,y,z)
```

I'm a bit wary of a Right Outer Join, as the documentation I've read says it can be replaced with a Left Outer, but it doesn't appear so for this case. It also seems a bit rare, which is making other devs nervous, so I'm being cautious.

So, three questions in one.

1. Is this correct?
2. Did I use the Right Outer Join correctly?
3. Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same thing?

EDIT: DB is MySQL

Comment: Yes, MySQL. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite it as a LEFT OUTER JOIN by using parentheses. In pseudo-SQL change this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM b
INNER JOIN c ON ...
RIGHT OUTER JOIN a ON ...
```

to this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    b INNER JOIN c ON ...
) ON ...
```

Comment: Could you clarify that once the USING(x,y) is added in there?

Comment: Can you turn the pseudo into actual? Since the discussion is about actual syntax, pseudo doesn't add much value.

Comment: That gave me what I needed Mark. Thanks. I think this will make some people more comfortable, even though other comments indicate I got the right join correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an EXISTS clause, which sometimes works better

```
SELECT
  a.id1,
  c.*
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableC c
 ON c.id1 = a.id1 AND EXISTS (
    select *
    from TableB b
    where b.id1=c.id1 and b.id2=c.id2)
WHERE
  a.id1 in (x,y,z)
```

As you have written it, it works because ANSI JOINs are always processed **top to bottom**.  Since you need to test B against C before joining to A, it is about the only way to write it without introducing a subquery `[(B x C) RIGHT JOIN A]`.  **However**, a bad query plan could perform all records in B and C `(B x C)` before right joining to A.

The **EXISTS** method efficiently uses the filter on A, then LEFT JOINs to C and for each C found, validates that it also exists in B (or discards).

#### Q's

1. Yes your query is correct
2. Yes
3. EXISTS should work better

Comment: +1 Thanks cyberwiki. I'm leaning towards the left join solution using parenthesis for precedence. Though I will experiment with this as well to test performance. This can be quite a large query in our DB.

Comment: It's your call, but EXISTS will in most cases perform better than INNER JOINs, let alone an embedded one.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need to start with TableA and then add tables B and C using joins. The only reason you even need TableA is to make sure you have a row for each parameter.

```
Select a.id1,c.*
From
  TableA a
  Left Join TableB b on a.id1=b.id1
  Left Join TableC c on b.id1=c.id1 and b.id2=c.id2
Where a.id1 in (x,y,z)
```

You need to do OUTER joins all the way across, or rows that are missing in B will also cause data from A to be filtered out of the result set. By joining C to B (instead of directly to A) you are using B to filter. You could do it with a complicated EXISTS clause, but this is cleaner.

Comment: I tried this, as I mentioned in the original question. But this produces extra rows that I do not want returned.